# share data between timer based Event (thread) and onLocationChange in android

Tags: android, multithreading, interface, locationlistener

Scenario-
I have a timer based Event thread where I am sending data (latitude and longitude) through post request. I have an onLocationChange method (my class implements on LocationListener) which is called on location change. It sets the new latitude and longitude value which should be called later by the timer Event.

The timer Event does not take the latest latitude and longitude values on location change event. When the timer event starts ,it does not call the onlocationchange method even when location is changed.

Here's the timer event:

/** This method calls the service every 10 seconds. */

```
protected void timerMethod(CookieStore cookieStore, String url) {
    int delay = 1000; // delay for 1 sec.
    int period = 10000; // repeat every 10 sec.
    timer = new Timer();
    if (timer != null) {
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                timerThread = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        sendpostRequest();  // calling the post method
                    }
                };
                timerThread.start();

            }
        }, delay, period);
    }
}
```

Here's the location change event:

/** This method is Called when the location has changed. */

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    isLocationChanged = true;  // setting a boolean value which is checked while posting the request
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Location change:::longitude::::" + location.getLongitude() + "latiude::::"
            + location.getLatitude());

    latClient = location.getLatitude();
    longClient = location.getLongitude();

}
```

Comment: What is the problem you're facing? Is something not working?

Comment: how to pass the latest latitude and longitude to the timer event thread. When the thread is running , onLocationChange method is not called even on location change.

Answer (score 0):

[Handlers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) is a way to communicate between threads, think you can use that :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the problem, but this solution is inefficient, its creating a bunch of Threads, which are very resource-heavy. Try something like this instead. I wrote this all in this window and didn't test, so make sure you do, but this I think is in the right direction given your problem description. MAKE SURE to call TimerLooper.terminate() at some point or you'll just have this thread churning away.

```
private void startTimerThread() {
    mTimerLooper = new TimerLooper(new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage() {
                onLocationChanged();
            }
        }, "timer-thread");
    mTimerLooper.start();
}

private class TimerLooper extends HandlerThread() {
    private static final int MSG_TERMINATE = 1;
    private static final int MSG_TIMER_EXPIRATION = 2;
    private Handler mCallback;
    private Handler mHandler;

    public TimerLooper(Handler callback, String name) {
        mCallback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLooperPrepared() {
        mHandler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                switch (msg.what) {
                    case MSG_TERMINATE:
                        mHandler.removeMessages(MSG_TIMER_EXPIRATION);
                        getLooper().quit();
                        break;
                    case MSG_TIMER_EXPIRATION:
                        mCallback.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                        mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(
                                10000, MSG_TIMER_EXPIRATION);
                        break;
                }
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(10000, MSG_TIMER_EXPIRATION);
        super.onLooperPrepared();
    }

    public void terminate() {
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_TERMINATE);
    }
}
```